# Windows install error: "We couldn't verify the product key. Please check your installation media."

Tags: windows-installation, windows-server-2012-r2

After entering the product key when installing Windows Server 2012 Standard, I get the error message.

```
We couldn't verify the product key.  Please check your installation media.
```

I have used the install DVD before, the disk surface is immaculate and the DVD drive did not seem to be struggling.  I tried 3 times with reboots in between - pretty sure I didn't mistype 3 times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you questioned and answered your own question in a matter of seconds?

Comment: I thought that was encouraged. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error if you are using a product key for the wrong product.  i.e. The key does not match the install media.

I think the key I was given was for Enterprise edition, but the install DVD was for Standard edition.  I got a new key for the correct product and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the machine (virtual or physical) has proper internet access. 
This solved it for me.